# How to use Gson to deserialize to a class containing an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, azure, gson

I'm using the Azure SDK, which uses Gson to serialize and deserialize objects to upload to their Mobile Services API.  I've had success doing this with a customs class of primitives only, as in the examples given in the [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples).  I'd like to do this with a custom class that contains an ArrayList. I'd even settle for a List or an Array, I'm not too picky.  Here's my class:

```
public class clsUser {
    private int UserID;
    private String UserName;
    private String UserStatus;
    public ArrayList<String> UserEmails;
```

Gson appears to serialize the class when sending to the server this way:

```
{ UserEmails: [ 'myEmail@gmail.com', 'myEmail2@yahoo.com' ],
  UserStatus: 'A',
  UserName: 'Scott',
  UserID: 1 }
```

On the server, I'm storing it all in a relational SQLServer database, so I'm keeping UserEmails as a String in there, and trying to bring it back out as an array.

However back on my Android/Gson/Client side, I'm getting an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

I suspect that the problem is that SQLServer is returning UserEmails with surrounding quotes. I'm not sure how to fix this. Complicating matters is that the Gson implementation is inside the Azure SDK, so I don't think I could even write a custom deserializer if I wanted to.  Any suggestions on fixing this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested you POJO and it works fine

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak I'm not sure what you mean.  The json object in the question isn't what Gson is receiving - it's what Gson *sent*.  Gson is receiving that data back *after* it's been inside a SQLServer table, which converted it to a string.

Comment: Ahh - I think you helped me answer my own question. If it's being returned as a string, then I need to use the server to manually convert it back to an array before returning it to the client....

Comment: I already tested it and serialisation works fine too.

Comment: are you sure the gson returning to android isn't empty? try to print it on logcat before trying to convert to your object.

Comment: @avjr - my struggle with that was that the Azure SDK was doing all the work, including the send/receive and the conversion. I haven't yet tried a workaround to make the api call without using the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad's comment helped me past this stumbling block.  If the problem is that the server is returning this field as a String, then all I needed to do was insert a step to convert it to an Array before returning the data to my client. (Yay for dynamic types in Javascript!)  My updated server script is below:

```
function lookup(request, response) {
    var UserID = request.query.UserID;
    if (UserID == null || isNaN(parseFloat(UserID))) {
        response.send(400, "Invalid Parameters (" + UserID + ")");
    } else {
        request.service.mssql.query("select ID UserID, Full_Name UserName, Email_Addresses UserEmails, Status UserStatus from User_List where ID=?;", [UserID], {
            success: function (results) {
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    //*** Added this line below to convert String back to Array ***//
                    results[0].UserEmails = results[0].UserEmails.split(',')
                    response.send(200, results[0]);
                } else {
                    response.send(200, []);
                }
            }, error: function (err) {
                response.send(500, {"Message" : "Lookup error = " + err});
            }
        });
    }
}
```